# Java Could not recognize the cedilla character in text

Tags: java, csv

I have small piece in code which requires to convert cedilla delimited file to comma separated file.

It worked fine for the normal test cases. But, when it went to real time, when the file is provided in unix environment, it could not recognize cedilla character in the text and failed to convert to proper CSV file.

Could you please help me out , if any one faced this issue.?
I need to pass the delimiter from the command line arguments.

Sorry if the question is in improper format, but i didnt recieve any help. so posted in stackoverflow.

Sample Code:

```
line = line.replace(Character.toLowerCase(context.getConfiguration().get("input.delimiter").charAt(0)), ',');

line = line.replace(Character.toUpperCase(context.getConfiguration().get("input.delimiter").charAt(0)), ',');
```

Comment: Provide the relevant code with input smaples and output.

Comment: What is your file encoding format ?

Comment: Users can provide file with any delimiter, that is the main plot. I have to pass the delimiter from the command line arguments and then code replaces the delimiter

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem you are facing is that in real environment default character encoding differs from the one on your local development machine. When processing the CSV file you should specify wich is the csv file encoding. 
You should check [How to read a file in Java with specific character encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096844/how-to-read-a-file-in-java-with-specific-character-encoding)