# Regarding word search error (Encoding error Java)

Tags: java, encoding

I have a list of french words where I am trying to search in my database. The words are "thé Mariage frères", "thé Lipton" etc.
While I am reading my file in java, it shows the words as "thÃ© Lipton", "thÃ© Mariage frÃ¨res". It fails to get the correct words.
I don't know how to correct my errors.

Help me, please!!!

Comment: Did you try anything? If yes then add your code to the question.

Comment: Check the database encoding, connection encoding, editor encoding, JSP and HTML encoding... it must be the same: UTF-8

Comment: @Ravikumar No, I didn't face this error earlier, So I don't have any clue to solve...

Comment: @Ravikumar   Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("French_Tea_keywords/filter_keywords.txt"));
  ArrayList<String> brand_Name = new ArrayList<String>();
  while (s.hasNext()){
   String token = s.nextLine();
      brand_Name.add(token);
  }
     String[] stringArr = brand_Name.toArray(new String[0]);
  s.close();

Comment: @prabhu Try creating Scanner object like this `Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("French_Tea_keywords/filter_keywords.txt"), "UTF8"); `

Comment: @Ravikumar Thank you so much!!! Solved..

Comment: @prabhu Nice, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating Scanner object like this

`Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("French_Tea_keywords/filter_keywords.txt"), "UTF8");`

Answer (score 0):

You file is in one encoding (maybe latin1/iso-8859-1) and you're reading your file  in another encoding.

See if this port helps [How to read a file in Java with specific character encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096844/how-to-read-a-file-in-java-with-specific-character-encoding)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(line);
    }
```