# Java- Can't figure out how to access content from a File I've created?

Tags: java, file, printing

So I have a file called boynames.txt with everything written into it, 
if I go like this:

```
   File getNames = new File("boynames.txt"):4
```

Then I just get a new file called "boynames.txt"
, but how do I get access to a file that I have already written inside of it already, but want access to it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a file in Java with specific character encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096844/how-to-read-a-file-in-java-with-specific-character-encoding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? You can read the file using a Scanner.

Source code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

class Demo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        File f = new File("boynames.txt");
        Scanner names = new Scanner(f);

        while (names.hasNextLine())
            System.out.println(names.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
demo > javac Demo.java
demo > java Demo
Tim
Joe
Bobby
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use java.io.FileReader:

```
import java.io.*;
//in a try catch do:
with(BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("boynames.txt"))) {
  String line = "";
  while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
  }
}
```

Ref:
1. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html
2. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html